# Construindo Menu Customizável em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu

Possuo um menu em minha aplicação, porém necessito adicionar uma tela de configuração onde o administrador do sistema seleciona o menu e escolhe se deseja habilitar ou desabilitar o item de menu, para todos os usuários da aplicação.

Pensei em criar uma tabela com os itens do menu e verificar se eles estão habilitados ou não (0 ou 1), e mostrar somente os que estiverem habilitados.

Eu nunca trabalhei com este tipo de configuração e não sei se esse meio que descrevi é a forma "correta" ou se funciona.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a lógica certa para desenvolver esta configuração?

### Menu

```
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Informações<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Afastamentos", "Index", "Afastamento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Aniversariantes", "Aniversariantes", "Usuario")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dados Cadastrais", "Index", "Usuario")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dependentes", "Dependente", "Usuario")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Férias", "Ferias", "Usuario")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Requerimentos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Todos", "Index", "Requerimento")</li>

                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Meus Requerimentos", "MeusRequerimentos", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Aposentadoria", "Aposentadoria", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Averbação", "Averbacao", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Certidão de Tempo de Serviço", "CertidaoTempo", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Exoneração", "Exoneracao", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Férias", "Ferias", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Mudança de Nivel", "Nivel", "Requerimento")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Outros", "Outros", "Requerimento")</li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    {
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuários<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastrar Novo", "Inserir", "Funcionario")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Listar", "Index", "Funcionario")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/GPWEB/logado.asp">Contracheque<span></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Antes de mais nada, [dê uma olhada nessas respostas que usam o `Authorize`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorize). Pode ser interessante como um ponto de partida. Depois disso edite sua pergunta e deixe-a mais específica.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu sempre usei o Authorize, o problema é que não possuo controle de acesso para esta aplicação. Terei apenas um usuário administrador, para habilitar ou desabilitar os menus para toda a aplicação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando que a habilitação não será atrelada ao usuário, pelo que eu entendi da sua pergunta, uma abordagem correta seria uma solução caseira.

## Models

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public int? MenuPaiId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Habilitado { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Action { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Controller { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MenuPaiId")]
    public virtual MenuItem MenuPai { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenusFilhos { get; set; }
}
```

## Uso no Controller

Procure criar um *Controller* comum, em que todos os outros *Controllers* sejam derivados dele. Coloque no seu *Controller* uma *Action* assim:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        var menu = contexto.MenuItens.Where(m => m.Habilitado).ToList();

        return PartialView(menu);
    }
```

## Views

Crie uma View para fazer seu menu em `/Views/Shared/Menu.cshtml`. Chame a *Action* que faz a *View* no seu Layout utilizando:

```
@Html.Action("Menu")
```

### A View Menu.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SeuSistema.Models.MenuItem>

<div class="container">
    <br />
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Informações<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach (var item in Model) 
                            {
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Nome, item.Action, item.Controller)</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    ...

                    <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/GPWEB/logado.asp">Contracheque<span></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: pensei em fazer desta forma, porém o que tinha em mente era menos "robusto" do que o que você postou.
Vou testar de daqui a pouco voltou com o resultado. Obrigado.

Comment: o que estava pensando era salvar o valor de cada menu(Habilitado) em um helpper( se é true ou false) e mostrar apenas os que forem true.
Editei a resposta com o menu que possuo hoje(menu.cshtml), Para adaptar para a forma que você demonstrou eu colocaria um @Model.Controller no lugar do controller, ou teria outra forma?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Você teria que tornar esse menu dinâmico. Precisa de um exemplo na *View*?

Comment: Se puder adicionar, ajudaria muito.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Veja se agora está mais claro.

Comment: Ficou sim, agora entendi o que você estava falando. Obrigado pela ajuda, era isso mesmo que precisava.