# C# MVC5 - Utilizando o OutputCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Comecei a estudar recentemente o `OutputCache` e suas utilizações, devido a uma utilização em um sistema corporativo.

Estou utilizando o `OutputCache` para carregar todos os menus que um usuário (logado) terá acesso. Porém, quero que a cada login ele recarregue novamente esse método (*action*), independentemente se o tempo (*duration*) esgotou ou não...

Alguém sabe se posso fazer isso via `override GetVaryByCustomString` no `Global.asax`? Se sim, como?

Abraços!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem como você está usando o `OutputCache` no `Global.asax`. Normalmente é feita uma decoração por *Attribute* no *Controller*. No seu caso, seria na *Action* de login:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=int.MaxValue, VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        /* Passos do seu método de login aqui */
    }
```

Ou, ainda, você pode usar uma *Action* para montar o menu e colocar a configuração de `OutputCache` nela. [Ensino isso nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49242/construindo-menu-customiz%C3%A1vel-em-asp-net-mvc/49246#49246):

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    [OutputCache(Duration=int.MaxValue, VaryByParam="none")]
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        /* Monte seu menu aqui */
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

Entendi a dúvida. Neste caso, acho que seria legal você forçar a expiração da cache na *Action* de *Logout*:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    var url = Url.Action("ControllerDeLogin", "Login");
    HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
    // Coloque o restante da lógica aqui.
}
```

Comment: Então, isso eu estou fazendo. Porém o que eu quero é que caso eu altere o acesso de um menu de um usuário, (tiro o acesso ao menu 'configuração' por exemplo), quero que ao fazer o logoff, e posteriormente o login, a minha 'actionresult Menu()' volte a ser executada, independente se o duration esgotou ou não...

Comment: @AntônioFilho Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Então, imaginei isso mesmo... Vou acabar colocando no Login, no [Get]. Essa opção é realmente a única?

Comment: Tem por Custom String, mas serve mais pra um escopo global, que não é seu caso.

Comment: Claro, entendo. Mas era isso mesmo! Então nem precisa utilizar o 'override GetVaryByCustomString' no 'Global.asax'... Vi bastante gente falando para usar esse método, mas teoricamente nem faz sentido...

Comment: Exatamente, mas não é todo mundo que busca uma solução mais adequada. Que bom que funcionou!