# Dados enviados ao Model limpam ao trocar de Página?

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Uma dúvida que me surgiu agora, baseado nesse post: [Construindo Menu Customizável em ASP.NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49242/construindo-menu-customiz%C3%A1vel-em-asp-net-mvc)

Se eu popular o meu model de *MenuItem* quando o usuário fazer login, ele vai popular, por exemplo, com os seguintes "módulos":

-Produtos

-Clientes

-Usuários

Eu estaria fazendo essa "população" do Model no meu **controller** de **Login**. Quando eu ir para uma outra action de outro controller, por exemplo a action **Cadastra** do controller **Usuários**, o meu model de *MenuItem* será esvaziado e terei que popular ele novamente, ou ele continuará preenchido com os módulos já preenchidos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há necessidade de passar o model do menu para cada tela.

Normalmente o menu é carregado no layout ou por uma partialview, assim toda vez que trocar de página, haverá a carga do menu.

Comment: Então basicamente, usando um **Layout**, se eu carregar nesse Layout o meu model, e usar esse layout nas outras **actions** de outros **controllers**, o meu Layout já estaria carregado, isso né?

Comment: Exatamente. O layout é a base da tela.

Comment: Show! Muito obrigado cara!